# Why GetText method returns empty string

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I wrote the following, after run this code it returns empty String value. Can any one suggest me to solve this problem?
Here I used gettext() method. It does not retrieve the link names.

**My code is:**

```
package Practice_pack_1;

import java.util.List;    

import org.openqa.selenium.By;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;    
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;    
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;    
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;    
import org.testng.annotations.Test;   

public class CheckingUncheckingCheckbox {
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void open()
    {
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://openwritings.net/sites/default/files/radio_checkbox.html");
}
@AfterTest
public void teardown() throws InterruptedException
{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.quit();
}
@Test
public void CheckingChkbox() throws InterruptedException{  
    WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fruits']"));
    List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("input")); 
    int sz= children.size();
    System.out.println("Size is: "+sz);
    for (int i = 0; i <sz; i++) 
    {
        boolean check= children.get(i).isSelected();
        if(check==true)
        {
            System.out.println(children.get(i).getText()+ "is selected");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(children.get(i).getText()+ "is not selected");
        }
    }  
}
```

}

**Output is:**

```
Size is: 3    
is selected    
is not selected 
is selected
PASSED: CheckingChkbox
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your application you may need to use `getAttribute("value")` instead of `getText()` as getText return the inner text.

Answer (score 1):

if you go and check your page HTML there is no inner text lies in  tag. So you can't use `getText()`.

I assume you are looking to get value of the input tags. If you check your HTMl agian there is a value attribute in input tag. You can read that value using,
 `getAttribute("value")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "." before your xpath, and make sure your xpath element is correct

try this `driver.findElement(By.id("fruits")).getText());`

Answer (score 0):

I've changed to way you programming to a "better" one, using the capacity of java
and its tools.

Actually the getText() is used to catch the text bewteen the tag like

```
<input id="input1" value="123"> getText() catches here </input>
```

and getAttribute() catches the value of a specified attribute.

```
<input id="input1" value=" getAttribute("value") catches here ">123</input>
```

That's my version of your code below.

```
@Test
public void CheckingChkbox() throws InterruptedException{  
  WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fruits']"));
  List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("input")); 
  System.out.println("Size is: "+children.size());
  for (WebElement el : children) 
  {
    if(el.isSelected())
    {
      System.out.println(el.getAttribute("value")+ "is selected");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println(el.getAttribute("value")+ "is not selected");
    }
  } // end for 
}// end CheckingChkbox()
```